# Nested (recursive) struct method calls: error: lifetime may not live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

The example should explain itself: a `Parser`, at a given point, will call an inner instance of itself to do some work (in another context). The text `Cursor` is passed to the inner `Parser`. After return, the outer `Parser` continues to 'eat' the rest of the text.
The idea is simple: pass the cursor around freely, until done.
But this won't compile.
My 2 questions:

- Can someone explain to me why this lifetime issue occurs? (like I'm 5 - I'm relatively new to rust)
- What are my alternatives? Perhaps a quick fix or maybe another design pattern, as long as there's no runtime cost with the cursor. (so, preferably no runtime borrow checking and such).

Note that the example does not include the different context (or state) of the 2 parsers.

```
use std::str::Chars;

struct Cursor<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
    chars: Chars<'a>
}

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    pub fn new(text: &'a str) -> Self {
        Cursor {
            text,
            chars: text.chars(),
        }
    }
}

struct Parser<'a> {
    cursor: &'a mut Cursor<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    fn new(cursor: &'a mut Cursor<'a>) -> Self {
        Parser {
            cursor,
        }
    }

    fn parse(&mut self) {
        self.cursor.chars.next();
        //...pass cursor to an inner Parser.
        self.one_level_deeper();
        self.cursor.chars.next();
        //continue with the current parser...
    }

    fn one_level_deeper(&mut self) {
        let mut parser = Parser::new(self.cursor);
        parser.parse();
    }

}

fn main () {
    let text = "AABBCCDDEEFF";
    let mut cursor = Cursor::new(text);
    let mut parser = Parser::new(&mut cursor);
    parser.parse();
}
```

Compiler output for this code:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:37:26
   |
21 | impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
36 |     fn one_level_deeper(&mut self) {
   |                         - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
37 |         let mut parser = Parser::new(self.cursor);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

Comment: `&'a mut Cursor<'a>` is pretty much always wrong -- there should be two lifetimes, not one.

Comment: One thing you can do is scrap the lifetime stuff and user ownership: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6e87db5d1636d9be2840bad0e5fc051

Comment: method `A` depends on `B` and method `B` depends on `A`, it's not "nested", "recursive", it's cyclic doesn't look good.

Comment: @cadolphs I forgot to mention that the 2 parsers have different state or context, so, moving self in and out is no solution in this case.

Comment: Untangling the two lifetimes from each other (as cdhowie suggested) *does* make it compile! https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=314e1df9121158da9cfc6567c082dd13 It blows up the stack because it has no base case, though I guess that's just the example.

Comment: Thank you, that simple change works. Will take some time for me to figure out why. The stackoverflow was intentionally not dealt with for brevity...and I guess in honor of this website.

Comment: To all: to understand the previous comment - the original post ended with "Bonus points: if you get this program to work, you will be magically prompted with the domain name of this site." But a moderator with lots of credits decided that was too much silliness and removed it.